# Convert spreadsheet tabs into dataframe using googledrive

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I want to turn a google docs spreadsheet into a dataframe, using the googledrive package (googlesheets is no longer maintained, and googledrive package seems to have a wider range of features).

I read the documentation for the googledrive package where it shows how to get the name of sheets, but it doesn't say how to get the sheet itself into a dataframe: https://googledrive.tidyverse.org/

```
library(googlesheets) #no longer maintained
sheet1 <- gs_title("Sheet")
tab1 <- as.data.frame(sheet1(for_gs, ws = "mytab", skip=1)) #I want this tab
#How to do the same thing in googledrive?
library(googledrive)
drive_find(type = "spreadsheet")
#Get name
x<-drive_get(id = "id_of_sheet") #this provides the id of the sheet1
#How to I get mytab from sheet1 and convert it into a dataframe?
```

I expected to be able to get sheet1 and turn this into a dataframe (as in the googlesheets examples), but there's nothing in the googledrive documentation to show how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
install.packages("devtools")    
devtools::install_github("tidyverse/googlesheets4")
library(googledrive)
library(googlesheets4)

drive_find(type = "spreadsheet")
#Get name
x<-drive_get(id = "id_of_sheet") #this provides the id of the sheet1
read_sheet(x)
```

https://github.com/tidyverse/googlesheets4

Comment: I can't seem to install googlesheets4 - I tried manually pasting the folder into my library, and also from GitHub, but it says: 'Error: Failed to install 'googlesheets4' from GitHub'

Comment: Yes devtools::install_github("tidyverse/googlesheets4")

Comment: This was working earlier in the year, but now I cannot install googlesheets4: "Failed to install 'googlesheets4' from GitHub: (converted from warning) cannot remove prior installation of package ‘backports’"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and was able to solve it using `read_sheet()` from `'googlesheets4'` and `'googledrive'` as indicated by a previous answer. However, simply using `read_sheet(x)` does not select a specific 'tab'. In order to select a specific 'tab' from the google sheet you must add a "range" argument `read_sheet(x, range = "mytab")`.

Full Example:

```
install.packages("devtools")    
devtools::install_github("tidyverse/googlesheets4")
library(googledrive)
library(googlesheets4)

drive_find(type = "spreadsheet")
#Get name
x<-drive_get(id = "id_of_sheet") #this provides the id of the sheet1
read_sheet(x) # only returns the first 'tab' in the google sheet
read_sheet(x, range = "mytab") # returns the tab you are interested  in
```

https://googlesheets4.tidyverse.org/

Comment: I get this error when trying to install googlesheets4 from github: : Failed to install 'googlesheets4' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) cannot remove prior installation of package ‘backports’